# searching for sub strings from multiple category arrays in PHP

Tags: php, regex, arrays, string, loops

I have a piece of text, which is around 1500 words long. I have to search for occurrences of certain words in this text and group them by categories. For example, if any of the following words are found: "dalmation", "boxer", "terrier" are found, then echo "Canines", if "lion", "leopard", "cheeta" are found then echo "Felines" and so on and so forth. Words found within other words are also acceptable, for example, "foxterrier".

I currently am using the following to go through the string:

```
$arrTitle = explode(" ", "Loren ipsum dolor ...............");
// For dogs:
foreach( $arrTitle as $key => $value){
    echo "Name: $key, Value: $value <br />";
    $words = array("dalmation", "boxer", "terrier");
    foreach($words as $word){
        if (stripos($value, $word) !== false) {
            echo "Canines Exists";
        }
    }
}

//For cats:
foreach( $arrTitle as $key => $value){
    echo "Name: $key, Value: $value <br />";
    $words = array("lion", "leopard", "cheeta");
    foreach($words as $word){
        if (stripos($value, $word) !== false) {
            echo "Felines Exists";
        }
    }
}

// ...Repeat the above for all categories.
```

The processing takes ages and also I'm not sure it's the most efficient way of doing things. Please can anyone help me find a speedier way of doing this? your help will  be most appreciated.

Comment: This sounds like homework ...

Comment: what, just because I used a simple example to explain the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could compose regexps of similar words, then do a single search for each.  Regexps aren't incredibly fast, but they're faster than running your own loops in PHP.  :-)

```
$groups = array(
  'Canines' => array("dalmation", "boxer", "terrier"),
  'Felines' => array("lion", "leopard", "cheeta")
);

foreach ($groups as $group => $members) {
  $pattern = "/" . implode("|", $members) . "/i";
  if (preg_match($pattern, $src)) {
    print $group;
  }
}
```

Meta code.  I haven't tested this.

The idea here is to remove the actual groups from your code.  After all, your data could be loaded from a database or some other source; the data structure and data should be separate.

By using the arrays as above, you can add new groups without changing the meat of the comparison code.  I.e. "Fish" become a group, not a chunk of code.

Comment: +1: You missed the parens around the imploded strings, but this is exactly what I was going to post. This answer would also benefit from some expansion to explain to the OP what is going on exactly.

Comment: You don't actually need the parens.  The vertical bar separates atoms, and parens merely group atoms.  Without parens, the vertical bars separate atoms at the top level of the regexp.  Thanks for the +1.  :)  I'll do some expansion.

Comment: take a look at preg_quote(). also, be aware there's a max pattern length of 65539.

Answer (score 3):

You're in my area here!

By far the fastest way is to `array_flip` and then use `isset` to check if the word exists, took me a long time to figure that one out. This will remain virtually instant for literally millions of words (searching in a string or array will never match this in speed), but it can eat up the RAM is such cases.

You should strtolower your `$words` first.

```
$arrTitle = strtolower($arrTitle);
$arrTitle = explode(' ', $arrTitle);

$words=array('dalmation', 'boxer', 'terrier');
$words=array_flip($words);

foreach($arrTitle as $key => $value)
    {
    echo "Name: $key, Value: $value <br />";
    if (isset($words[$value])) echo $value.' Exists <br/>';
    }
```

Comment: I'm going to run some benchmarks on this. Interested in seeing the comparison vs. regexes -- it seems like an elegant solution.

Comment: It's several orders of magnitude faster than RegEx, especially on long string. I use this for a text classifier I wrote in PHP which has to search against literally millions of words, and it does it in seconds. Takes about 3 days using RegEx or strpos. But as I said, the only downside is that is eats RAM, though this will only be an issue if you have hundreds of thousands of words, and you can just make sure to `unset` as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

As an optimization for your current script you should be checking for all words in the same loop instead of running a foreach on $arrTitle multiple times.  Or as an alternative just use stripos on the entire document for each word.

If this is for an actual production site and needs to be run repeatedly I wouldn't be doing this in PHP at all.  A database (MySQL or Solr) with a proper index on your documents would produce much faster results.